# Drawing normals in LWJGL messes with lighting

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, lighting

My issue is fairly straightforward: Drawing normals in LWJGL causes the light source to only apply to the model until it is manually updated after initialization. Here's the lighting initialization:

```
static Vector3f lightPosition = new Vector3f(-500f, -100f, 500f);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT0);
GL11.glLightModel(GL11.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, asFloatBuffer(new float[]{0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1f}));
GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, asFloatBuffer(new float[]{1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1f}));
```

And here's my code for drawing the normals (loaded from the Standford Bunny model):

```
for (Face f : bunnyModel.faces){
Vector3f n1 = bunnyModel.normals.get((int)f.normal.x - 1);
GL11.glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);
Vector3f v1 = bunnyModel.vertices.get((int)f.vertex.x - 1);
GL11.glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
Vector3f n2 = bunnyModel.normals.get((int)f.normal.y - 1);
GL11.glNormal3f(n2.x, n2.y, n2.z);
Vector3f v2 = bunnyModel.vertices.get((int)f.vertex.y - 1);
GL11.glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
Vector3f n3 = bunnyModel.normals.get((int)f.normal.z - 1);
GL11.glNormal3f(n3.x, n3.y, n3.z);
Vector3f v3 = bunnyModel.vertices.get((int)f.vertex.z - 1);
GL11.glVertex3f(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? When I disable normals, lighting works fine on everything but the model. But when I enable them, the bunny receives light, but no other surfaces do.

Comment: Do the other surfaces have normals as well? or possibly inward-pointing normals?

Comment: No, the only normals are contained within the model.

Comment: If the only normals in the scene are the ones on the model, then the rest of the scene will not be lit correctly without normals.

Comment: Ah, okay. Would you mind posting that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Actually, I have another question. How do I generate normals for shapes? Google isn't exactly helping, as I don't really know what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When lighting is enabled in OpenGL, all polygons will be lit according to their normals. If no normals are given to a polygon, that object's normal will default to the vec3 `{0, 0, 1}`. Basically, enable lighting, draw your model, then disable lighting and draw the rest of your scene.

Calculating per-face normals is fairly easy, here is a little getNormal() function I wrote:

```
//Feel free to use this for whatever you want, no licenses applied or anything.

//p1, p2, p3 - Vertices of triangle
public Vector3f getNormal(Vector3f p1, Vector3f p2, Vector3f p3) {

    //Create normal vector we are going to output.
    Vector3f output = new Vector3f();

    //Calculate vectors used for creating normal (these are the edges of the triangle).
    Vector3f calU = new Vector3f(p2.x-p1.x, p2.y-p1.y, p2.z-p1.z);
    Vector3f calV = new Vector3f(p3.x-p1.x, p3.y-p1.y, p3.z-p1.z);

    //The output vector is equal to the cross products of the two edges of the triangle
    output.x = calU.y*calV.z - calU.z*calV.y;
    output.y = calU.z*calV.x - calU.x*calV.z;
    output.z = calU.x*calV.y - calU.y*calV.x;

    //Return the resulting vector.
    return output.normalise();
}
```

[[OpenGL Documentation]](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Calculating_a_Surface_Normal)

[[Another similar question]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305642/how-to-find-surface-normal-of-a-triangle)

[[More on the cross product]](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/routines/r_cross.htm)

But... per-face normals can look sort of... bad. If you want a smoother result, you should use per-vertex normals. Here's the difference:

Per-Face:
[image: You can see the triangles...]

Per-Vertex:
[image]

Make sure not to use per-face normals for things like cubes, cubes are flat, not curved. Per-Vertex normals are to be used in situations where you want to make something look more smooth and realistic (skin, potato, pillow, etc.).

For calculating per-vertex normals, you basically average all the normals of the joined polygons like so:

[image: It's de average]

If you happen to get the model looking entirely black or the parts facing you are invisible, try reversing the order that you put the points into the getNormal() function (or negating the normal, the error is due to the fact that the normal is facing inward, not outward).

Hoped this helped!

Comment: Brilliant answer, but how would I go about modifying the method you included to calculate the normals of quadrilaterals instead?

Comment: @mproncace If the quad is "flat", you simply put the first 3 points from the quad into the getNormal() function. Otherwise, given 4 points p1, p2, p3, and p4, the normalized vector is (getNormal(p1, p2, p3) + getNormal(p2, p3, p4)).normalise() Also, a good thing to know is that wen OpenGL draws quads, it is actually drawing 2 triangles. Graphics cards were designed for drawing triangles. Oh, I also corrected my getNormal() function (I remembered to normalize the output vector), so if you've copied-pasted it, you should probably do that again.

Comment: @mproncace Are you using GLSL yet? I would reccomend putting this problem in a new question with some more info.

Comment: I actually just deleted that comment, as I realized I had completely messed up in terms of calling the method. So, new problem again. I'm assuming that when you said to average the face vectors, you meant to average the coordinates of them. However, when I try to create a vector out of these new coordinates, LWJGL throws an error when I attempt to normalise, saying that it's a Zero Length Vector.

Comment: @mproncace I meant to average the *normals* of the joined faces, not the coordinates of the faces themselves. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Alright, I've figured out how to average them, but doing so returns a zero length vector.

Comment: @mproncace Can you try and turn this into another question with some source code supplied? I'm kind of lost as to what to do here...

Comment: I eventually completely gave up. It's honestly more trouble than it's worth, considering it's just the terrain. New question though, is it possible to make a flashlight effect without normals?

Comment: @mproncace Yes, but it won't look as good. The lighting won't have the same realistic effect. What I would do is color each polygon based on the distance from it to the player, then do some trickeynometry and light only the stuff in a circle in front of the player. Sorry to hear you gave up, you should go back later and try again. CAN YOU PLEASE ASK NEW QUESTIONS FOR YOUR NEW QUESTIONS? You will get people more experienced than me answering, and gain reputation. Good luck in your programming.

Comment: @mproncace Basically, you create a ray formed by the direction the player is looking in originating from his position. Then you find the shortest distance from each vertex to that ray, and color the scene accordingly. [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a02-_lines.html) is a good tutorial on the math.