# How to fix lighting rotating with model?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

My goal is to create small scene with lighting. However, lighting seem to rotate together with my rendered object (test cube).

In most responses I've read I should use GL11.glLight in projection and model matrix mode, I assumed. Please correct me if I'm wrong. However, result is that lighting works, but it intensity varies with cube rotation.

Here is my example prepared for Stack:

```
package main;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

public class Stack {

    static int rot;
    static int rot2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack r = new Stack();
        r.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            createWindow();
            initGL();
            run();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void run() {
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            try {
                render();
                Display.update();
                Display.sync(60);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        Display.destroy();
    }

    private void render() {
        rot++;
        rot2++;
        rot2++;
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0,GL11.GL_POSITION,floatBuffer(5,0,10,0));

        GL11.glTranslatef(0f, 0.0f, -7f);
        GL11.glRotatef(rot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glRotatef(rot2, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        renderCube();
        GL11.glRotatef(-rot2, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glRotatef(-rot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glTranslatef(0f, 0.0f, 7f);
    }

    public FloatBuffer floatBuffer(float a, float b, float c, float d) {
        float[] data = new float[] { a, b, c, d };
        FloatBuffer fb = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
        fb.put(data);
        fb.flip();
        return fb;
    }

    private void renderCube() {

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.7f, 0.7f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        GL11.glEnd();
    }

    DisplayMode displayMode;

    private void createWindow() throws Exception {
        Display.setFullscreen(false);
        DisplayMode d[] = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();
        for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            if (d[i].getWidth() == 640 && d[i].getHeight() == 480 && d[i].getBitsPerPixel() == 32) {
                displayMode = d[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        Display.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
        Display.setTitle("Stack Example");
        Display.create();
    }

    private void initGL() {
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
        GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glClearDepth(1.0);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, (float) displayMode.getWidth() / (float) displayMode.getHeight(), 0.1f, 100.0f);

        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING); // enable lighting
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT0); // enable light 0
        GL11.glLightModeli(GL11.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL11.GL_TRUE);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        GL11.glColorMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL11.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

I expected lighting to be static if GL11.glLight is used before transformations. I would be very glad for explanation, cause most tutorials I look up use shaders to achieve lighting effect.

Comment: I'm confused too. I tried using this - https://relativity.net.au/gaming/java/Lighting.html  example, replacing only rendering part - from part to cube - with the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for tip, I will edit the question to include all the code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lighting is calculated based on the local *surface normal vector* of each point at which the light model is to be evaluated.

You do not provide any normal vectors for your cube, so the GL will use *the very same* normal vector for each and every vertex. As a result, all your cube faces are lighted as if they are facing to the same direction.

Comment: Oh I see. So as I understand, surface vector is like direction to reflect light? It's still really new to me. Do I need to calculate normal for every quad?

Comment: It is not the direction to reflect light, but more or less the local orientation of the surface (which detemines in which direction(s) the light will be reflected). And yes, typically, the normals are part of the geometry data of the model, and 3D modelling tools also support normal caluclations and modification. In your case, a single normal per cube face would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you! I used method from this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777757/drawing-normals-in-lwjgl-messes-with-lighting - and It works perfectly.